# React Router V6 - Redirect inside Route Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following code from the V5 Documentation:

```
    <Route exact path="/">
      {loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> : <PublicHomePage />}
    </Route>
```

I know that I have `Navigate` instead of `Redirect` in V6, but `Navigate` seems not to work the exact same way:

```
    <Route></Route>
      {loggedIn ? <Navigate to="/dashboard" /> : <PublicHomePage />}
    </Route>

Uncaught Error: [Navigate] is not a <Route> component.
```

How can I archieve this with React Router V6?

Comment: Can you show me how you're using `Navigate` to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react-router v6 `<Route>` it's the only component that's able to be child of `<Routes>`:

So change this logic:

```
<Route>
    {loggedIn ? <Navigate to="/dashboard" /> : <PublicHomePage />}
</Route>
```

to this:

```
<Route path="/" element={loggedIn ? <Navigate to="/dashboard" /> : PublicHomePage}
```

You can also checkout this article: [Private Route in react-router v6](https://dev.to/iamandrewluca/private-route-in-react-router-v6-lg5)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <Route path="/" element={ <Navigate to="/dashboard" /> } />
```

Because Route return the element for a path, so for the path '/', return Navigate for redirect

Answer (score 0):

**V5**

```
<Route exact path="/">
  ...
</Route>
```

**V6**

```
<Route path="/" element={...}/>
```